# Corba not working with Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, corba

all. I have some code like this

```java
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitRef", "NameService=corbaloc::testsrv:2809/NameService");
        ORB orb = ORB.init((String[])null, props);

        org.omg.CORBA.Object objRef = orb.resolve_initial_references("NameService");
        NamingContextExt ncRef = NamingContextExtHelper.narrow(objRef);

        CommunicatorHdb impl = CommunicatorHdbHelper.narrow(ncRef.resolve_str("TestServiceName"));

        System.out.println("My valid impl = " + impl");
```

It is valid code for desktop version. If i use this code for webapp (with Jetty or Tomcat 7) - I see exception "BAD_PARAM" for string

```java
        CommunicatorHdb impl = CommunicatorHdbHelper.narrow(ncRef.resolve_str("TestServiceName"));
```

Why do it not work with tomcat?

Comment: I found 50% of error. In desktop version String _id = "IDL:Communicator/CommunicatorHdb:1.0". But in webapp version String _id = "IDL:org.kirill.Communicator/CommunicatorHdb:1.0". How fix it for correct IDL

Comment: Is `TestServiceName` bound to your `NamingContext`?

Comment: Yes. Of course. I found error. That was case space in module idl error.

Comment: Just a hint. If the NS IOR is known at compile time, you can simply use `NamingContextExt ncRef = NamingContextExtHelper.narrow( orb.string_to_object("corbaloc::testsrv:2809/NameService"))`